# FB Graph API - comments - in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I have FB comments [from here](https://graph.facebook.com/35819517694_10151061675702695/comments?access_token=xyz) - . What is the standard way to use, display it in iOS, (probably UIWebView)? I want  web or mobile view of FB comments (like [this](https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/384492_307851252589634_1222763805_n.jpg)), like comments box plugin. But comments plugin probably requires some web setup, which I don't have. How to display comments in my app? I know I can parse and use Graph API and display it manually, but I need standard way, view.